# jPOS connectivity with Posiflex printer through Java application

Tags: java, printing

I want to integrate a Posiflex printer with my application, where the logical name is "PP Demo" and the device model is PP-8900.

The printer is connected to my system and is able to print with Posiflex software. How can I integrate it with my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to paste the needed dll files into the lib of my java that's it, and the jpos.xml file is mentioned in the code...

```
package practice;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.print.Book;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;


public class PrintableComponent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PrintableComponent example3 = new PrintableComponent();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    // --- Private instances declarations
    private final static int POINTS_PER_INCH = 72;

    /**
     * Constructor: Example3
     * <p>
     * 
     */
    public PrintableComponent() {

        // --- Create a new PrinterJob object
        PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

        // --- Create a new book to add pages to
        Book book = new Book();

        // --- Add the cover page using the default page format for this print
        // job
        book.append(new IntroPage(), printJob.defaultPage());

        // --- Add the document page using a landscape page format
        PageFormat documentPageFormat = new PageFormat();
        documentPageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
        book.append(new Document(), documentPageFormat);

        // --- Add a third page using the same painter
        book.append(new Document(), documentPageFormat);

        // --- Tell the printJob to use the book as the pageable object
        printJob.setPageable(book);

        // --- Show the print dialog box. If the user click the
        // --- print button we then proceed to print else we cancel
        // --- the process.
        if (printJob.printDialog()) {
            try {
                printJob.print();
            } catch (Exception PrintException) {
                PrintException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Class: IntroPage
     * <p>
     * 
     * This class defines the painter for the cover page by implementing the
     * Printable interface.
     * <p>
     * 
     * @author Jean-Pierre Dube <jpdube@videotron.ca>
     * @version 1.0
     * @since 1.0
     * @see Printable
     */
    private class IntroPage implements Printable {

        /**
         * Method: print
         * <p>
         * 
         * @param g
         *            a value of type Graphics
         * @param pageFormat
         *            a value of type PageFormat
         * @param page
         *            a value of type int
         * @return a value of type int
         */
        public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pageFormat, int page) {

            // --- Create the Graphics2D object
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            // --- Translate the origin to 0,0 for the top left corner
            g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());

            // --- Set the default drawing color to black
            g2d.setPaint(Color.black);

            // --- Draw a border arround the page
            Rectangle2D.Double border = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, pageFormat.getImageableWidth(),
                    pageFormat.getImageableHeight());
            g2d.draw(border);

            // --- Print the title
            String titleText = "Printing in Java Part 2";
            Font titleFont = new Font("helvetica", Font.BOLD, 36);
            g2d.setFont(titleFont);

            // --- Compute the horizontal center of the page
            FontMetrics fontMetrics = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            double titleX = (pageFormat.getImageableWidth() / 2) - (fontMetrics.stringWidth(titleText) / 2);
            double titleY = 3 * POINTS_PER_INCH;
            g2d.drawString(titleText, (int) titleX, (int) titleY);

            return (PAGE_EXISTS);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Class: Document
     * <p>
     * 
     * This class is the painter for the document content.
     * <p>
     * 
     * 
     * @author Jean-Pierre Dube <jpdube@videotron.ca>
     * @version 1.0
     * @since 1.0
     * @see Printable
     */
    private class Document implements Printable {

        /**
         * Method: print
         * <p>
         * 
         * @param g
         *            a value of type Graphics
         * @param pageFormat
         *            a value of type PageFormat
         * @param page
         *            a value of type int
         * @return a value of type int
         */
        public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pageFormat, int page) {

            // --- Create the Graphics2D object
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            // --- Translate the origin to 0,0 for the top left corner
            g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());

            // --- Set the drawing color to black
            g2d.setPaint(Color.black);

            // --- Draw a border arround the page using a 12 point border
            g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(12));
            Rectangle2D.Double border = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, pageFormat.getImageableWidth(),
                    pageFormat.getImageableHeight());

            g2d.draw(border);

            // --- Print page 1
            if (page == 1) {
                // --- Print the text one inch from the top and laft margins
                g2d.drawString("This the content page of page: " + page, POINTS_PER_INCH, POINTS_PER_INCH);
                return (PAGE_EXISTS);
            }

            // --- Print page 2
            else if (page == 2) {
                // --- Print the text one inch from the top and laft margins
                g2d.drawString("This the content of the second page: " + page, POINTS_PER_INCH, POINTS_PER_INCH);
                return (PAGE_EXISTS);
            }

            // --- Validate the page
            return (NO_SUCH_PAGE);

        }
    }

} // Example3
```